# How can I find all Items that meet a certain condition in JSON Data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, loops

I get data from an API-Call. I have got a many to many relationship - I will explain it with people an movies. One movie is seen by many people and one person can watch many movies. 
So in the Angular Frontend, when you click on a person, you should get a more detailled view of this person including a list of its watched movies.

When I run this code (person-detail.component.ts):

```
  public selectedperson: any = []
/*Array that contains data from the selected person*/
  public movie: any = []
/*Array that contains all the movie-person connections (movie-name and person_id)*/
  public selectedmovie: any = []
/*array that should contain all the movies the selectedperson has watched*/
/*some code*/
getMovies(){
    const url ='http://localhost:4000/api/people-movies';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(movie => {
      this.movie = movie;
      this.selectedmovie=this.movie.find(item=>
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.movie.arrayLength; i++) {
            if(item['person_id']===this.selectedperson.person_id)
            {
              return true;
            }
          return false;
        }
        });
      console.log(this.selectedmovie, this.selectedperson.person_id);
      return this.selectedmovie;
    });
  }
```

It does not work - but without this loop (and if I leave the If-statement):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < this.movie.arrayLength; i++) {
}
```

It returns only one movie of this person - so it stops as soon as it has found a movie. But since I want to list all the movies I need the loop.

So what am I doing wrong with the loop?

Edit: 
sample Data in selectedperson (is already filled): 
selectedperson:

```
[{"person_id"=34, "name"="john"}]
```

movie (get this data from API Call with the mentioned URL):

```
[{"person_id"=33, "movie"="Titanic"}{"person_id"=33, "movie"="Star Wars"}{"person_id"=34, "movie"="Titanic"}{"person_id"=34, "movie"="Star Wars"}{"person_id"=34, "movie"="Indiana Jones"}{"person_id"=35, "movie"="Titanic"}]
```

wanted final result (for the person with the id 34)

```
Titanic
Star Wars
Indiana Jones
```

Comment: I don't really get what you're doing. You're trying to populate `selectedmovie`- which is an empty array- by activating the `find` function on itself...

Comment: Could you write your sample data and desired result? Array of `selectedmovie`, `movie` and `selectedperson`?

Comment: also, you're making a `for` loop but do not use `i` at any point inside... so what the point of it?

Comment: use filter if you want to get all the elements which matches certain condition. find returns only first match

Comment: @Gibor selectedmovie is not an empty array - but I did left the code for this out to keep my question as uncomplicated as possible. I use i just to count and so loop through the whole array

Comment: @butterfly then we need to know whats inside of it to answer your question properly. But as far as I understood, `movie` array is a list of objects like `{ movieName: ..., person_id: ...}`, so it means if you have person_id and want to find all movies for it- you need to loop (or `filter`) on this, not `selectedmovie`. and about the `for` loop- it is really unneccessary, at least in the way you use it. There is no point in `for` loop when you don't use the `i`, because it means everything inside stays the same.

Comment: @butterfly basically, in the `for` loop you perform this `item['person_id']===this.selectedperson.person_id` comparison X times (according to `movie` length), but `item` does not change, nor does `this.selectedperson.person_id`. So its the same compatison over and over again on the **same movie**.

Comment: @Gibor I added some sample data to improve understanding - I will overthing the loop according to your explanation

Comment: @StepUp: I added some sample data to improve understanding

Comment: @butterfly The answer I gave will give you exactly what you want :)
I just added a `map` on the returned array to return the array only with movie names, and not the whole `{person_id, movie}` object.

Comment: @butterfly P.S if my answer did help, please confirm it with the green V so people can know this question is answered :)

Comment: @Gibor - surely - I just try to solve the problem first and in the end mark all useful answers :)

Comment: @butterfly feel free to ask more here if there are parts of the answers you do not understand or struggle with , or you encountered a new problem on the way :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201534/discussion-between-gibor-and-butterfly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but i'll start with what I think is the solution for you:

```
getMovies(){
    const url ='http://localhost:4000/api/people-movies';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(movie => {
      this.movie = movie;
      this.selectedmovie=this.movie.filter(item=> item['person_id'] === this.selectedperson.person_id );
      console.log(this.selectedmovie, this.selectedperson.person_id);
      return this.selectedmovie.map(movie.movie);
    });
  }
```

Now, what is wrong with your code:

1. you try to populate an empty array `selectedmovie` by activating `find` on itself, but it is empty... Instead, populate it with the movies- found in the `movie` array.
2. you're using `find`, which a simple look at documentation ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) would make it clear it only returns the first element satisfying the test function. Instead, used `filter`, which is kinda the same but goes through the whole array and returns all the objects satisfying the test.
3. you make a for loop without using the `i` inside it - a strong sign you don't actually need that loop.
4. There is no need to return "true" or "false" when the whole check is a single boolean expression, it would return it inline.
5. just a side not, your varibale names are really hard to follow. For example, an array containing movies is better be called "movies", and when you iterate over it with an array function, each element can be called "movie". using same name for both is really confusing. Also try to use camel-case notation (selectedMovie), would make names clearer.

**NOTE: my solution will only return the array from "getMovies" the way you want it, because `.map` is chained on the return value. If you want `selectedmovie` to be populated with only movie-names as string and not the whole movie-perosn_id object, just chain the `.map` to the `filter`, like so:

`this.selectedmovie=this.movie.filter(item=> item['person_id'] === this.selectedperson.person_id ).map(movie => movie.movie);`

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result like this:

```js
const movie = [
   {"person_id":33, "movie":"Titanic"},
   {"person_id":33, "movie":"Star Wars"},
   {"person_id":34, "movie":"Titanic"},
   {"person_id":34, "movie":"Star Wars"},
   {"person_id":34, "movie":"Indiana Jones"},
   {"person_id":35, "movie":"Titanic"}
];

let selectedperson = [{"person_id":34, "name":"john"}];

let moviesByPerson = movie.filter(f=>
    selectedperson.some(s=> f['person_id'] == s['person_id']));

console.log(`moviesByPerson: `, moviesByPerson);
```

In your code:

```
getMovies(){
    const url ='http://localhost:4000/api/people-movies';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(movie => {
      this.movie = movie;
      this.selectedmovie = movie.filter(f=>
           selectedperson.some(s=> f['person_id'] == s['person_id']));

      console.log(this.selectedmovie, this.selectedperson.person_id);

      return this.selectedmovie;
    });
  }
```

In addition, try to move your HTTP calls into services as it is good practice to separate concerns. [As Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

> Components shouldn't fetch or save data directly and they certainly
>   shouldn't knowingly present fake data. They should focus on presenting
>   data and delegate data access to a service.

Comment: Thank you for the detailled answer - i throws me the following Error message though: ```Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.```

Comment: @butterfly please show what `movie` has. It looks like movie has another format than it is shown in a sample data.

Comment: corrected a typing errof from me and the error message dissappeared - your code is for the right data format - but the variable "selectedmovie" is still empty

Comment: @butterfly could you create a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)?

Comment: @butterfly try to use `==` instead of `===`. What does  `console.log(this.selectedmovie, this.selectedperson.person_id);` show?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
this.selectedmovie = this.selectedmovie.filter(item => {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.movie.arrayLength; i++) {
     if (item['person_id'] === this.selectedperson.person_id) {
        return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
});
```

Note: Javascript array.find method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues, like mentioned, you are using `find`, which will return just the first match (if exists). You are looking for `filter` to filter the movies that match the id. Also you are trying to return from `subscribe`, which does not work. Also I would change your practices a bit. **DON'T** use `any`, it defeats the purpose of **Type**Script. So type your data, for example using interfaces, it will help you, since compiler can tell you if your doing something that does not conform to your models, which makes debugging far easier!

Also I would move all http-requests to a service, the component would only subscribe to the result of that http-request. So all in all, I suggest the following:

```ts
interface Movie {
  person_id: number;
  movie: string;
}

interface Person {
  person_id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Service:

```ts
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

// ...

getFilteredMovies(id: number) {
  const url ='http://localhost:4000/api/people-movies';
  return this.http.get<Movie[]>(url).pipe(
    map((movies: Movie[]) => {
      return movies.filter((m: Movie) => m.person_id === id)
    })
  )
}
```

Component:

```ts
movies = <Movie[]>[];

selectedPerson = <Person>{ person_id: 34, name: "john" };

constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService
    .getFilteredMovies(this.selectedPerson.person_id)
    .subscribe((data: Movie[]) => {
      this.movies = data;
    });
}
```

So we handle the filtering in the service already and component only subscribes. **IF** you though are calling this function in other places where you **don't** want the filtering to be performed, then instead do the filtering in the component.

**[STACKBLITZ demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbpsj5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it - thanks erveryone for trying to help, especially @Gibor!
Here is the code for people who face a similar problem: 
However - know that this code is by no meand perfect and has to be improved in many ways (e. g. with an loop to find all movies). I just post it here in the hope it helps someone with similar problems ...
component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-detail',
  templateUrl: './people-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people-detail.component.css']
})
export class PeopleDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: any = []
  public selectedperson: any = []
  public movies: any = []
  public moviesByPerson: any = []

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient, 
    public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

getPeople()
{
  const person_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('person_id')
  const people_url ='http://localhost:4000/api/people'
  const movies_url ='http://localhost:4000/api/person-movie'
  this.http.get(people_url).subscribe
    (data => 
      {
        this.data = data;
        this.selectedperson=this.data.find
        (item=>
          {
            if(item['person_id']===person_id)
            {
             return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        )
        this.http.get(movies_url).subscribe
    (movies => 
      {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.moviesByPerson=this.movies.filter(item => item.person_pk === this.selectedperson.person_pk)
      }
    )
    console.log(this.selectedperson, this.moviesByPerson)
        return this.selectedperson, this.moviesByPerson
      }
    )
}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getPeople()
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
<div><span>ID: </span>{{selectedperson.person_id}}</div>
<h1>{{selectedperson.name}}</h1>
<p>{{selectedperson.age}}</p>
<p></p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movies</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{moviesByPerson[0].movie}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{moviesByPerson[1].movie}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{moviesByPerson[2].movie}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```